# Java wildcard for parameter

Tags: java, generics, parameters, wildcard

Is there a way to achieve something like this? This code is similar to what I want to achieve.

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
    MultiCall(new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(){{
        put(1, 2);
        put(3, 4);
    }}, (i, j) -> {
        System.out.println(i + j);
    });

}

public void MultiCall(HashMap<?, ?> map, BiConsumer<? super ?, ? super ?> func){
    ...
    map.forEach(func);
}
```

The problem here is BiConsumer, I need the wildcard to be the super of HashMap's wildcard.

The linter says this

```java
Required type: BiConsumer <? super capture of ?, ? super capture of ?>
```

However, upon doing `? super ?`, says it need to be a Type. But the Type currently is a wildcard.

Comment: Side note:  [Double brace initialization is bad.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java)  Avoid doing it.  As of Java 9, you can write `Map.of(1, 2, 3, 4)` instead.

Comment: I see, I also wasn't aware that it could create a memory leak. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your method generic by adding type parameters for the map's key and value types:

```
public <K, V> void MultiCall(
    HashMap<K, V> map,
    BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> func){
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. I wasn't aware of this syntax.